# Escapists shows blank frame when launching Steam

Tags: steam, technical-issues, the-escapists

I have a problem,

Whenever I launch the escapists on Steam, a blank frame shows up.
[image]
I have reinstalled like 10 times. When i move the window and switch back, it copies the pixels under it and puts it like this. Only basic buttons and dropdowns are shown, but unoperable.

---

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium through VirtualBox. The host OS is Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a wineskin wrapper rather than a VirtualBox, it works more conveniently, acts like the normal Steam (Because I don't have the game on Wineskin, but Steam to allow installation of windows Steam games), and I can play windows games on it.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of bugs start when the game was downloaded with errors or interrupted,

Go to your Steam Libary, Right click the game > Properties > Local Files > Verify Intergrity of game cache

Comment: Thanks for you effort. However, the problem was not fixed. Even after uninstalling, reinstalling, verifying, running.

Answer (score 1):

I run Alpha v0,799 of the escapists and can't upgrade because of the way I downloaded it - it happened to my sister and twice with me, I just keep a working file of the game on my USB so if it breaks (which it hasn't done in a while) I can reinstall, though you will lose progress. Mine lost all speech apart from rollcall names, guards yelling and peoples names, and I couldn't do favours. The title screen boxes were blank, but I know how to navigate the menu so I was fine. I don't know if this bug is still in the latest version, I will be downloading soon hopefully as I want to try the map editor, and the original post was 3 months ago, so I don't know if it's sorted itself out in that time.

If you paid money for the game and can't reinstall without spending money, I suggest you contact steam or the alternative buyer where applicable, but it's not advisory to buy (pay for) the game from anywhere other than Steam.

Hopefully this helps, if it's not already sorted!

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably just talk to Steam and see if they can help. Did the game come like that, or had it been used before the bug?

Comment: Its okay. I actually fixed it anlong time ago with a Steam wineskin wrapper. I will give credit for information